# Xamrin.Forms Entry Cell How to change font size for Placeholder

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I am thinking if i can change font size for placeholder on `EntryCell` without change `fontSize` for Text on `EntryCell`?

Is There away to change font size  for Placeholder without change font size for Text

```
 Code = new EntryCell { Label = "Code:*", Text = "", Keyboard = Keyboard.Default, Placeholder = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a custom renderer for android. Here I'm modifying the HintTextColor(placeholder). You can modify the font in a similar way.

```
  using System;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using communityhealth;
using Android.Graphics;
using communityhealth.Android;


[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (MyUsernameEntry), typeof (MyUsernameEntryRenderer))]
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (MyPasswordEntry), typeof (MyPasswordEntryRenderer))]
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (MyEntry), typeof (MyEntryRenderer))]

namespace communityhealth.Android
{
    public class MyEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged (e);
            if (e.OldElement == null) {   // perform initial setup
                // lets get a reference to the native control
                var nativeEditText = (global::Android.Widget.EditText) Control;
                // do whatever you want to the textField here!
                nativeEditText.SetBackgroundColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
                nativeEditText.SetTextColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.White);
                Typeface font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset (Forms.Context.Assets, "Neris-Light.otf");
                nativeEditText.TextSize = 14f;
                nativeEditText.Typeface = font;
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyUsernameEntryRenderer : MyEntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged (e);

            if (e.OldElement == null) {
                // lets get a reference to the native control
                var nativeEditText = (global::Android.Widget.EditText) Control;
                nativeEditText.Hint = "Username";
                nativeEditText.SetHintTextColor (global::Android.Graphics.Color.White);
                nativeEditText.TextSize = 18f;
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyPasswordEntryRenderer : MyEntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged (e);

            if (e.OldElement == null) {
                // lets get a reference to the native control
                var nativeEditText = (global::Android.Widget.EditText) Control;
                nativeEditText.Hint = "Password";
                nativeEditText.SetHintTextColor (global::Android.Graphics.Color.White);
                nativeEditText.TextSize = 18f;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @darrellbooker .. i will accept your answer when i have  a time to try it :)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no.

There is no API in Forms to change the Placeholder font size. Instead, you could create your own custom control to do this, or use a custom renderer to modify the placholder in the native view.

Comment: could you please add some code i am developing android project .